# How to include auto Indendation features into Tkinter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have included, below code block for **Auto-Indendation** feature into basic notepad.

```
  import os
  import tkinter as tk
  from tkinter import ttk
  from tkinter import *
  from custom_text import CustomText
  from text_Line_Number import TextLineNumbers

  class notebook():
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.geometry("300x300")

            self.text_expand = tk.Text(self.root)
            self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.text_expand, orient="vertical", 
                       command=self.text_expand.yview)
            self.text_expand.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

            self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
            self.text_expand.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

            self.text_expand.bind('<:>', self.indendation)

            self.text_expand.config(background='#2C363E', foreground='white')

        def indendation(self, event):
            #Find line starting & its position:
            colon = ":"
            index = self.text_expand.search(r':\Z', "insert", backwards=True, regexp=True)

           line_no = self.text_expand.index("end-1c linestart")
           col_pos = self.text_expand.index("end-1c lineend")
           print(line_no, "Need to add next line after this count as <line_no+1>")
           print(col_pos, "This is actually the cursor position")
           #self.text_expand.insert(line_no, "\n\t")
           newLine = float(line_no)+1.4
           print(newLine)

           column = 0

           #self.text_expand.insert(tk.END,     )
           self.text_expand.mark_set(tk.INSERT, "%d.%d" % (float(line_no)+1.0, column+4))
           self.text_expand.index(tk.INSERT)
           print(self.text_expand.see("insert"))


        def run(self):
           self.root.mainloop()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
        inst = notebook()
        inst.run()
```

But when : pressed, it returns below code, instead of navigating cursor to the **next line(1 line + 4 space/ 1 tab space.)**

[image: Please find the screenshot]

```
    5.0 Need to add next line after this count as <line_no+1>
    5.12 This is actually the cursor position
    6.4
    None
```

Kindly help me on this issue. I have included only dummy code.

Comment: What does _"I have included only dummy code"_ mean? Did you post code that doesn't actually reproduce the problem?

Comment: No, this is not related to problem or, error code. Actually I tried to move cursor to the next line form the position of : to the next line + 4 white space/ tab space. But it only returns the position instead of move the cursor.

Kindly look into this & help me on this. Thanks in advance.